# how to check magento soap api session id is valid or not

Tags: magento-1.9, session, soap-api-v2

I am using magento soap api for mobile application, I want to know how to check the soap api session id is valid or expired?

I want to know so if that session id expires I can regenerate the session id again.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution myself, it was a simple trick just make a soap call with the current sessionId if the API return the results then the sessionId is valid else create a new one

Please see the below example that I am using

```
try{
        $result = $proxy->catalogProductList((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId, 'filters' => null));
        $valid = true;
    } catch (Exception $e){
         $response['error_code'] = $e->getCode();
         $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

so now if the api call return the result then it is fine else regenerate the new sessionId.